# Accessing class member from another class, is it better to use pointer or friend?

Tags: c++

I am trying to access and change a member variable of one class from another class. I will try to explain my problem the best I can. I have a class called solution, that handles the bulk of my project and it has a few different classes as member variables. Solution has a Matrix (class) member variable that I am trying to modify from other classes.

```
class Solution{
public:
void DoSomething();
private:
Class1 mObject1;
Class2 mObject2;
Matrix mSolutionMatrix;
};

Solution::DoSomething()
{
mObject1.SetPointer(&mSolutionMatrix); // Set the pointer to solution matrix
mObject2.SetPointer(&mSolutionMatrix);
mObject1.ModifyMatrix(); // Modify the matrix in Class1
mObject2.ModifyMatrix(); // Now try to modify the solution matrix after object 1 has changed it.
}
```

Then if I have Class1 and Class2, only defining one since the principle of what I am trying to do is the same. They both are trying to modify solution.mSolutionMatrix

```
class Class1{
public:
void SetPointer(Matrix* pointer);
void ModifyMatrix();
private:
Matrix* mPointerToMatrix; // This is where I am stuck
};

void Class1::SetPointer(Matrix* pointer)
{
mPointerToMatrix = pointer;
}
void Class1::ModifyMatrix()
{
// Do something to solution matrix
}
```

I am wondering if this is possible by using pointers, or would it be better to make Class1, Class2 and solution friends of each other. I hope I explained it well enough.

Comment: It would be best not to let other classes modify your class member at all. Using "friend" is kind of acceptable if you have two classes that were developed together and are intended to be used together. Passing a non-const pointer or reference to a member around to other, non-friend classes, seems to be unacceptable under most circumstances.

Comment: Your situation is too abstract to comment on the design issues. Can you tell the class owning the matrix what to do with it? Instead of passing this responsibility to a different class.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest totally flipping your design upside-down and have the solution matrix accept object input instead. Then you can just use the object's public interface to do the mutations of the solution matrix. In this way you don't need friendship or public mutation of another class's public state.

```
Solution::DoSomething()
{
    mSolutionMatrix.modify(mObject1);
    mSolutionMatrix.modify(mObject2);
}
```